# Multiple views in one url address in Django

Tags: python, django

The problem is this:

I have two classes Posts and Pubs in **models.py**, I need them to be displayed simultaneously on the main page,
 I have in **views.py** file:

```
def pubs_list(request):
    publications = Pubs.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'app/pubs_list.html', {'publications': publications})


def posts_list(request):
    posts = Posts.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'app/posts_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

in urls.py:

```
    path('', views.posts_list, name='posts_list'),
#    path('', views.pubs_list, name='pubs_list'),
```

accordingly, if we uncomment the second condition, then the first will work.

The question is, is it possible to make 2 views have one path, or is it somehow necessary to register in the view? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, each URL can only be handled by one view.

For the example in your question, it would be straight forward to make a single view that fetches the posts and publications.

```
def pubs_and_posts(request):
    publications = Pubs.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    posts = Posts.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'app/pubs_.html', {'publications': publications, 'posts': posts})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a unique view with both models:

urls.py

```
path('', views.posts_and_pubs, name='posts_and_pubs_list'),
```

views.py

```
def posts_and_pubs(request):
    posts = Posts.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    publications = Pubs.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'app/posts_list.html', {'posts': posts, 'publications': publications})
```